# How I do to obtain the solution for Random Effects using package lme4?

Tags: r, lme4

I have a model similar to this:

```
model=lmer(y ~ (1|ID) + Factor.A + Factor.B, data=df)
```

I would like to obtain the solution of random effects, but I only could obtain the solution of fixed effects, using this codes:

```
coef(summary(model))
summary(model)
```

I tried this code too:

```
coef(model)
```

but I suppose this output is not for the solution of random effects. Is there a code to obtain the solution of random effects using the package lme4 or another one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "solution" here. You can see the estimated random effects using `ranef(model)`, and there are some automatic plotting methods like `dotplot(ranef(model))`.

Comment: See also [this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122009/extracting-slopes-for-cases-from-a-mixed-effects-model-lme4).

Comment: @Marius, yes is this. Is there a way to obtain the standard error of these estimates?

Comment: @Marius, please insert your answer!! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only the `lme4` package, you can most conveniently get the *conditional modes* along with the *conditional standard deviations* via `as.data.frame(ranef(fitted_model))`:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
as.data.frame(ranef(fm1))
##     grpvar        term grp     condval    condsd
## 1  Subject (Intercept) 308   2.2575329 12.070389
## 2  Subject (Intercept) 309 -40.3942719 12.070389
## 3  Subject (Intercept) 310 -38.9563542 12.070389
## ... etc.
```

I'm not sure I would be comfortable calling these "standard errors" - there's a whole can of worms here about what kind of inferences you can make on the observed conditional values of random variables ... according to [Doug Bates](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg04913.html)

> Regarding the terminology, I prefer to call the quantities that are
>   returned by the `ranef` extractor "the conditional modes of the random
>   effects". If you want to be precise, these are the conditional modes
>   (for a linear mixed model they are also the conditional means) of the
>   random effects B given Y = y, evaluated at the parameter estimates.
>   One can also evaluate the cond[i]tional variance-covariance of B given Y
>   = y and hence obtain a prediction interval.

Answer (score 2):

I think clearly stating your question, and what you are trying to do would be helpful. However, based on the comments, I think I know what you are trying to do.

As @Marius said, `ranef(model)` will give you the intercepts.

the package `arm` has a `se.ranef` function that gives you "standard errors". I am not sure how these are calculated. See this link to make sure that it is doing what you want it to:

https://rdrr.io/cran/arm/man/se.coef.html

So all together:

```
library(lme4)
model=lmer(y ~ (1|ID) + Factor.A + Factor.B, data=df)

ranef(model)

library(arm)
se.ranef(model)
```

Comment: `arm::se.ranef()` returns the same values as `as.data.frame(ranef(fm1))$condsd`, i.e., the conditional standard deviations described in @ben's response